# Filtering HABTM with AND Condition

Tags: php, sql, filter, cakephp-2.0, has-and-belongs-to-many

I'm trying to filter some car parts depending on the categories they are related to.
A part can have many categories (in the code they are called tags), so I chose the HABTM relation with a join table.

Filtering works so far, but only with an OR condition with cake using the SQL command IN.
But I'm trying to filter only the parts that have **all** the selected categories, so I need to use an AND condition on the category array.

Here's the extracted code from the controller:

```
$this->Part->bindModel(array('hasOne' => array('PartsTagsJoin')));

$params['conditions'] = array('AND' => array('PartsTagsJoin.tag_id' => $selectedCats));
$params['group'] = array('Part.id');

$parts = $this->Part->find('all',$params);
$this->set('parts',$parts);
```

$selectedCats is an array like this: array(1,2,3,4,5);

The SQL output is:

```
'SELECT `Part`.`id`, `Part`.`name`, `Part`.`image`, `Part`.`image_dir`, `Part`.`time_created`, `Part`.`time_edited`, `Part`.`user_id`, `Part`.`editor_id`, `Part`.`notice`, `User`.`id`, `User`.`username`, `User`.`password`, `User`.`usergroup_id`, `User`.`realname`, `PartsTagsJoin`.`id`, `PartsTagsJoin`.`part_id`, `PartsTagsJoin`.`tag_id` 
FROM `c33rdfloor`.`parts` AS `Part` 
LEFT JOIN `c33rdfloor`.`users` AS `User` ON (`Part`.`user_id` = `User`.`id`) 
LEFT JOIN `c33rdfloor`.`parts_tags_join` AS `PartsTagsJoin` ON (`PartsTagsJoin`.`part_id` = `Part`.`id`)  
WHERE `PartsTagsJoin`.`tag_id` IN (1, 4, 8, 24)'
```

How can I filter the parts that have every id that is committed through the $selectedCats Array.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got it working thanks to this blog post:

http://nuts-and-bolts-of-cakephp.com/2008/08/06/habtm-and-join-trickery-with-cakephp/

It seems to be a little tricky to filter entries with **all** selected tags:
The key in achieving an AND relation is to get the count of the selected cats and match it with the ones of the query inside the group parameter.
This line did it:

```
$params['group'] = array('Part.id','Part.name HAVING COUNT(*) = '.$numCount);
```

In the End the code looked like this (for people interested in a solution):

```
// Unbinds the old hasAndBelongsToMany relation and adds a new relation for the output
$this->Part->unbindModel(array('hasAndBelongsToMany'=>array('PartsTag')));
$this->Part->bindModel(array('hasOne'=>array(
         'PartsTagsJoin'=>array(
             'foreignKey'=>false,
             'type'=>'INNER',
             'conditions'=>array('PartsTagsJoin.part_id = Part.id')
         ),
        'PartsTag'=>array(
              'foreignKey'=>false,
              'type'=>'INNER',
              'conditions'=>array(
                  'PartsTag.id = PartsTagsJoin.tag_id',
                  'PartsTag.id'=>$selectedCats
)))));

$numCount = count($selectedCats); // count of the selected tags

// groups the entries to the ones that got at least the count of the selected tags -> here the 'AND' magic happens
$params['group'] = array('Part.id','Part.name HAVING COUNT(*) = '.$numCount); 

$parts = $this->Part->find('all', $params); // sends the query with the params

$this->set('tagCategories', $categories);
$this->set('selectedCats', $selectedCats);
$this->Part->recursive = 4;
$this->set('parts',$parts);
```